# Implicit boolean conversion of Objective-C object literal always evaluates to true ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-warnings, deprecation-warning, xcode9.2

I recently downloaded Xcode 9.2 and updated my project settings to recommended. Now I'm getting this warning in my code for all the places where I've used *assert* for eg:

`assert(@"Must be implemented by subclass");`

What is the proper alternative for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Objective-C, you want to call `NSAssert()`, not `assert()` (which is a C function).

```
NSAssert(NO, @"Must be implemented by subclass");
```

If you want to continue using `assert()`, you should treat it like a C function.

```
assert(0); // <-- Note: no message is provided
```

You might get away with

```
assert(/* Must be implemented by subclass */ 0);
```

or

```
assert("Must be implemented by subclass" == NULL); // <-- Note: No `@`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `assert` condition is a string which will always pass the test.

You should be checking a condition in the `assert`

Answer (score 0):

a) assert needs a condition to check. you treat the string as a condition and it is non-null... do

b) you use a NSString and not a char* so you pass objC object to C which wont work in this case either ... do

```
assert(codition & "Message");
```

c) you should use NSAssert for ObjC Code .. do

```
NSAssert(codition, @"Message");
```